# The sum of integer parts of $2k/n$ over $k=1,\dots,n-1$

Tags: summation, induction, ceiling-and-floor-functions, direct-sum

Let

$$
  S_n= \left[\frac{2}{n}\right]+\left[\frac{4}{n}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{2(n-1)}{n}\right]
$$

where $n$ is an odd integer such that $n\geqslant 3$, and $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$.
Show that 
$$S_n=\frac{n-1}{2}.$$

I thinked about using induction ! But no results.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the sequence for an actual value of $n$?

Comment: The formula $S_n = [(n-1)/2]$ is not true. Better is $S_n = (n+7)/2$ for $n\geqslant 3$ odd.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger i think it's true in case n is even

Comment: I think you have an indexing problem.  I'm getting the answer is [n/2] + 4.

Comment: Try is with n = 8.  2,4,6 => 0 (total 0); 8,10,12,14 => 1 (total 4), 16, 18 => 2 (total: 8)

Comment: Try it with 8. 2,4,6 => 0; 8,10,12, 14 => 1+1+1+1 = 4;  16,18 => 2+2.  Total = 8.  Try it with 26:  2, 4, 6 .....,22, 24 => 0;  26, 28,.....50=>1 + 1 + 1+.... =13.  50 52 => 2 + 2 = 17.

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal see my edit

Comment: Okay, you've edited it from being true for all numbers, to only true for even numbers, to only even numbers greater than 6, to only odd numbers greater than 7.  When are you going to reach the final step that this is simply NOT TRUE.  EVER.  Take n = 57.  2, 4, 6,.... 56 all yield 0.  58, 60, ....  112 all yield 1.  So that adds up to 23 which is [$\frac {57}{2}$].  Then 114 and 116 yield 2 each for a total of 27 = [$\frac {57}{2}$] +4.  The answer for ALL n $\ge$ 1 is ALWAYS $[\frac {n} {2}] + 4$.  You simply have an indexing error.

Comment: For it to be true you want $S_n = [\frac 2 n] + .... + [\frac {[2(n - 1)]}{n}]$.  In that case, then $S_n = [\frac {n-1}{2}].$  ALWAYS.  for all $n \ge 1$.

Comment: @fleablood fixed !!!

Comment: Almost.  Now the answer is [n/2].  Need one fewer term to make it [n-1/2]

Comment: @user233658: the formula is true for $n = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

if $n  =2k;$ n is even:

Then $[\frac {2}{n}]$ to $[\frac {n -2}{n}]$ will all be 0.  $[\frac {n}{n}]$ to $[\frac {2n -2}{n}]$ will be 1 and that be a total of $\frac n 2$.   $[\frac {2n}{n}]$ and $[\frac {2(n+1)}{n}]$ both equal 2 so the sum is $[\frac {n}{2}] +4$.

If $n = 2k + 1;$ n is odd.

Then $[\frac {2}{n}]$ to $[\frac {n -1}{n}]$ will all be 0.  $[\frac {n + 1}{n}]$ to $[\frac {2n -2}{n}]$ will be 1 and that be a total of $k = [\frac n 2]$ .   $[\frac {2n}{n}]$ and $[\frac {2(n+1)}{n}]$ both equal 2 so the sum is $[\frac {n}{2}] +4$.

Comment: See the edit please

Comment: I saw the edit.  It is still wrong and doesn't address that my answer covers odd number greater than 7.

Comment: For n>3 it's true :)

Comment: No!  IT IS NOT!!!!!!!

Comment: Ah, you *have* corrected the edit finally.

Comment: [2/k].......... [2(k-1)/k] it's true for odd K >3

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$[a]  = a - \{a\}$$ where $\{ a\}$ denotes the fractional part of $a$
Now we may rewrite the sum as $$S_n=\frac{(n+1)*(n+2) }{n}+ \{\frac{2}{n}\}+\{\frac{4}{n}\}+........+\{\frac{2(n+1)}{n}\}$$
Notice that if $a$ is congruent to $c$ modulo $b$ and $c<b$ then $\{\frac a b\} = \frac c b$
If $n$ is odd then $2*i$ is a permutation of all residues $i$ of $n$, thus we may evaluate the above sum as 
$$S_n=\frac{(n+1)*(n+2) }{n}+ (n-1) + 2 + 2/n = \frac {2*n*(n+1)+2}{n}
 $$

Comment: Shouldn't those be subtractions and shouldn't your answer be $\frac {2(n+1)-2}{n}$?

Comment: See the edit please

Answer (score 0):

You have an indexing error and your statement is simply not true ever because you  have added too many terms.

$S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1}[\frac {2i}{n}] = \sum_{i = 1; i < \frac n 2}[\frac {2i}{2}] + \sum_{i \ge [\frac n 2]}^{2(n - 1)}[\frac {2i}{n}] +  \sum_{i = 2n}^{2(n + 1)}[\frac {2i}{n}]=  \sum_{i = 1; i < \frac n 2}0 + \sum_{i \ge [\frac n 2]}^{2(n - 1)}1 +  \sum_{i = 2n}^{2(n + 1)}2 = 0 + [\frac{n}{2}] + 2 + 2 = [\frac{n}{2}] + 4$

To get the result you want you want:

$S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{2(n - 2)}[\frac {2i}{n}] = \sum_{i = 1; i < \frac n 2}[\frac {2i}{2}] + \sum_{i \ge [\frac n 2]}^{2(n - 2)}[\frac {2i}{n}]=  \sum_{i = 1; i < \frac n 2}0 + \sum_{i \ge [\frac n 2]}^{2(n - 2)}1= 0 + [\frac{n -1}{2}]  = [\frac{n-1}{2}]  $

The weird thing is you keep changing restrictions to your equation hoping it will be true for some conditions when it has never been true for any conditions because you have added too many terms.

Comment: I think it's true now ;)